# How to read parse image in OpenCV when the input is from CGI

Tags: python, opencv, numpy, post, cgi

I've got a simple HTML form POSTing data to my Python script. The code I'm using is below, and it doesn't work:

```
form = cgi.FieldStorage()
filedata = form['upload']

image = cv2.imdecode(filedata,0)
```

It gives me the following error:

> image undefined, cv2 = ,
>   cv2.imdecode = , filedata =
>   FieldStorage('upload', 'ch.png',
>   '\x89PNG\r\n\x1...z\x81\xec\x15\xe0\x00\x00\x00\x00IEND\xaeB`\x82')
>
> : buf is not a numpy array, neither a
>   scalar
>         args = ('buf is not a numpy array, neither a scalar',)
>         message = 'buf is not a numpy array, neither a scalar'

How would I go about processing my uploaded image without writing it to disk first, and then reading it again?

Comment: The error message kinda hits at it -- you need to pass a numpy array, not a FieldStorage instance to `imdecode`. [`numpy.fromstring`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.fromstring.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved:

I had to convert the data first to a numpy array.

```
image = cv2.imdecode(numpy.frombuffer(filedata,dtype=numpy.uint8),0)
```